# ansible hangs on checking a directory

Tags: nfs, ansible

I have an ansible playbook that mounts an nfs share. It first makes sure that the destination directory exists:

```
  - name: create /mnt/tmp
    file: path=/mnt/tmp
          recurse=yes
          state=directory

  - name: mount nfs 
    mount: src=10.0.0.2:/data/apache/htdocs
           name=/mnt/tmp
           fstype=nfs
           fstab=/etc/fstab
           state=mounted
           opts="user,rw,hard,intr,auto"
```

This works fine the first time I run the playbook but if I rerun it it hangs on the `create /mnt/tmp` task.

Am I doing it wrong? How do I debug the problem?

I changed the playbook to this and this "solved" the problem in a rather unelegant way:

```
  - name: check if /mnt/tmp exists
    stat: path=/mnt/tmp
    register: p

  - name: create /mnt/tmp
    when: not p.stat.exists
    file: path=/mnt/tmp
          recurse=yes
          state=directory

  - name: mount nfs
    mount: src=10.0.0.2:/data/apache/htdocs
           name=/mnt/tmp
           fstype=nfs
           fstab=/etc/fstab
           state=mounted
           opts="user,rw,hard,intr,auto"
```

Surely there's a better way.

Comment: Why are you using `recurse=yes`?

Comment: because `/mnt` doesn't exist - I know...why not mount i `/mount`? Because I'm trying to reproduce an existing (and at present badly configured) machine. Next step will be to fix whatever is bad.

Comment: It's not what this parameter is for.

Comment: Oh...OH. So, it was actually recursing through the entire nfs mount doing stuff. Thanks for clarifying. The correct fix will be creating each part independently (or is there a more convenient way to do a `mkdir -p` style directory creation?)

Comment: It should work this way out of the box.

Comment: From the `file` module docs, the `state` parameter indicates: *["If 'directory', all immediate subdirectories will be created if they do not exist..."](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html)*